# Overstayed on Schengen visa in Denmark, applied for permanent spouse visa, will it be granted?

Tags: visa, schengen, overstay

I stayed 9 days extra in Denmark on a Schengen visa. Unaware of the overstay, I applied for a spouse type in the overstay period.
This is when a cop there told me that you are overstaying. Meanwhile, the application for the spouse visa was rejected as it was applied during the overstay.

Then when i came back to my home country I applied for a Schengen visa again. It was rejected.

Now I have applied again for the spouse visa from my home country and waiting for the decision!

Comment: How did it end up?

Comment: Could you please add that as answer? Thanks!

Comment: Well! I got the spouse visa, but the Danes sure took their time. It was granted 6 months after the application! The delay was the most unpleasant thing ever! But it was all good in the end! Sorry for the 'very' late reply though!

Answer (score 3):

According to OP:

> Well! I got the spouse visa, but the Danes sure took their time. It
>   was granted 6 months after the application! The delay was the most
>   unpleasant thing ever! But it was all good in the end! Sorry for the
>   'very' late reply though!

Comment: The OP actually posted that comment as an answer and then a moderator deleted the answer.  We should perhaps appeal to the moderator to undelete the answer. The OP got one upvote on the answer and deserves the reputation.

Comment: @phoog I don't see deleted posts here so I wouldn't know

Comment: I figured; that's why I posted my comment :-)

Comment: phoog it was converted to a comment.  @StrongBad can maybe advise, but this isn't the place for that.